# Where are RCT2 save files stored?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

On Windows 8.1, RCT2 recognizes my save files, but when I look in the Program Files (x86) folder, they aren't there. Where are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're stored in [VirtualStore](http://portableapps.com/node/35519) within the Users folder.

C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\GOGcom\RollerCoaster Tycoon 2\Saved Games

Replace **NAME** with your Windows username. Non-GOG versions of the game are stored in a different folder in the Program Files (x86) folder (e.g. "Infogrames").

C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\