# Where is progress (completed scenarios list) recorded in RollerCoaster Tycoon 2?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

1. I'm migrating from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and would like to keep my *RollerCoaster Tycoon 2* progress (completed scenarios list).
2. However, copying, from the installation folder, files edited this year, did not copy the progress.
3. But copying the entire installation folder did the trick.

Which is the file I can't locate that records the progress?

I have the CD version, by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are RCT2 save files stored?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181865/where-are-rct2-save-files-stored)

Comment: @OrangeDog Nope. I'm talking about the game progress, not the parks' save files. One may have progress in the game without saving one's parks for playing later. The progress is the "checks" near the challenges names, not the parks with buildings per se.

Comment: Are there any kind of `.sc#` files you can find? I was looking at the open source reimplementation of the game and I see something like that for the "scenarios" and wonder if that's what the original game used also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/404324/72346 might be the same as RCT1